# Trying to get property 'charge' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting "Trying to get property 'charge' of non-object " while trying to this code.

```
<td>{{getAmount($data ?? ''->charge)}} @lang($basic->currency)</td>
<td>@lang($transaction->remarks)</td>
<td>{{ dateTime($transaction->created_at, 'd M Y h:i A') }}</td>
```

Comment: you are getting the property charge on an empty string...

Comment: `$data ?? ''->charge` is crazy and makes no logical sense. Your code says "1) if $data is null, then replace it with an empty string (`''`). 2) read the "charge" property from the result of step 1." Clearly, an empty string cannot have properties. Tell me, what did you _expect_ this code to do? Perhaps you misunderstood the syntax somehow. It's not actually clear what you really wanted to achieve. Swapping a variable for one of another type is rarely a good approach in any scenario but especially not here.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem at line 1
Replace this:

```
<td>{{getAmount($data ?? ''->charge)}} @lang($basic->currency)</td>
```

With this:

```
<td>{{getAmount($data ?? $transaction->charge)}} @lang($basic->currency)</td>
```